# How to match the second occurrence in php?

Tags: php

I have a text file:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
doc_root = "/www/"                                                   
user_dir =                                 
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php"
enable_dl = On              
;cgi.force_redirect = 1     
;cgi.nph = 1                
;cgi.redirect_status_env = ;
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1          
;fastcgi.impersonate = 1;
;fastcgi.logging = 0   
;cgi.rfc2616_headers = 0
```

I want to match `/www/` here's what I've tried so far:

```
<?php
$phpini = file_get_contents('/etc/php.ini');
preg_match('/doc_root = ".*/', $phpini, $doc_root);
echo $doc_root[0];
?>
```

But it prints `doc_root = "/www/"` instead of `/www/`. How can I do this ?

Comment: Turn `.*` into a capturing group `(.*)` and then `var_dump($doc_root)` to see what else it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to your exact question, but how about you use [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) for files:

```
$phpini = parse_ini_file('/etc/php.ini');
echo $phpini['doc_root'];
```

Or for the currently loaded `php.ini`:

```
echo get_cfg_var('doc_root');
```

Or the current setting (could have been modified by .htaccess etc.):

```
echo ini_get('doc_root');
```

Another option would be:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: Thank you, both `echo get_cfg_var('doc_root');` and `echo ini_get('doc_root');` seem to be the easiest